# Overload wrapped function with generic in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, macos

**First example**

```
func foo<T>(_ t: T) -> String {
    return bar(t)
}

func bar<T>(_ t: T) -> String {
    return "Other"
}

func bar<T: StringProtocol>(_ t: T) -> String {
    return "String"
}

foo("") // "Other" // Why not "String"?
bar("") // "String"
bar(1) // "Other"
```

**Second example** (more complex)

First example can be resolved by type checking, but in this example it is impossible.

```
func foo<T>(_ t: (T) -> String) -> String {
    return bar(t)
}

func bar<T>(_ t: (T) -> String) -> String {
    return "Other"
}

func bar<T: StringProtocol>(_ t: (T) -> String) -> String {
    return "String"
}

foo { (string: String) -> String in return "" } // Other // Why not "String"?
bar { (string: String) -> String in return "" } // String
bar { (int: Int) -> String in return "" } // Other
```

Overloads are resolved statically. Since T inside foo() is unconstrained, it picks the overload of bar() with an unconstrained T. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

As per current Swift implementation, the function which is more specialized, meaning it has constraints who are a superset of the constraints of the other overloaded function; overloading will pick the more specialized function.

So, I can't think of better alternative than making `foo` conform to `StringProtocol`.

Regarding why there is not a better hack around, I would like to quote from Swift [documentation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/Generics.rst#overloading) which talks about how nested or more specialized generic type should be resolved.:

> This amounts to run-time overload resolution, which may be desirable,
>   but also has downsides, such as the potential for run-time failures
>   due to ambiguities and the cost of performing such an expensive
>   operation at these call sites. Of course, that cost could be mitigated
>   in hot generic functions via the specialization mentioned above.
>
> Our current proposal for this is to decide statically which function
>   is called (based on similar partial-ordering rules as used in C++),
>   and avoid run-time overload resolution. If this proves onerous, we can
>   revisit the decision later.

Answer (score 0):

Talking of work around. 
You can do it as follows.

```
func foo<T>(_ t: T) -> String {
    if let str = t as? String {
     return bar(str)
    }
    return bar(t)
}

func bar<T>(_ t: T) -> String {
    return "Other"
}

func bar<T: StringProtocol>(_ t: T) -> String {
    return "String"
}
```

Again speaking of work around.

```
func foo<T>(_ t: @escaping (T) -> String) -> String {
    if let clsr = t as? (String) -> String {
        return bar(clsr)
    }
    return bar(t)
}

func bar<T>(_ t: (T) -> String) -> String {
    return "Other"
}

func bar<T: StringProtocol>(_ t: (T) -> String) -> String {
    return "String"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it could be too easy :) I've updated my question. Look at second example. There I can't check types.